# Django: Instanciation of a model using a hash of a ForeignKey

Tags: django, rest, security, hash

I'm currently trying to implement an API in Django Rest for a class project that's supposed to store data in a secure way.
I have two different models:

```
class Driver(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
```

and

```
import Driver

class Car(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
     driver = models.ForeignKey(Driver, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Currently, there's a mapping between cars and their respective drivers.
I'd like to map a car not to it's driver, but to the result of a hash function applied to it's driver name. Something like:

```
import Driver
import hashlib 

class Car(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
     driver = hashlib.md5(models.ForeignKey(Driver, on_delete=models.CASCADE).name).hexdigest()
```

I know what I wrote above is probably heretical in Django, it is just to convey the idea of what I want to do!
I thought about overriding the Car model's init, save, create functions in order to do this, but have strictly no idea what is the good option.
At the end of the process I'd like that there's no mapping between the Car and it's Driver, but a Driver's car could be found using the hash of his name.

Let me know if this is unclear or if you need more precision!

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you don't want to use a `ForeignKey`, just save a hash in the database. This means you won't be able to use database functionality to fetch the driver but would always need to first evaluate the hash in python before you can fetch the `Driver` object. Correct?

Comment: Mmm, why would this be more secure? What's the actual threat model you're trying to work against? If you want to make it harder to enumerate the cars and drivers available, for instance, use `id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)` to generate random hex IDs for your models (and thus, foreign keys).

Comment: @dirkgroten exactly! The purpose being that if someone gets access to the database, he won't be able to link cars to their drivers (I know there are lot of other security issues, I plan to use a private key to perform the hash in a second time)

Comment: @AKX the threat is that someone that would access the DB could know the car of each driver (which we don't want to happen, a driver's car is considered private information that they'd like to hold secret)

Comment: If an attacker gains access to your database, what's preventing them from running the same hash function to figure out the relationships anyway?

Comment: well if that's the purpose, it's useless as @AKX mentioned.

Comment: I totally agree, if the hash function is known by the attacker. In a second time I'd like to use a hash function that make use of a private key that's not stored in the database, so that someone would need to get access to both the DB and the private key to gain access to all the information

Answer (score 0):

You want to remove the explicit link from `Car` to `Driver` so you should not use a `ForeignKey`. Note the disadvantage is that you can't use a database JOIN to retrieve the car for a driver but will have to perform an extra query.

Create methods on your `Car` and `Driver` models to assign a driver and to retrieve the car:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    ...
    driver = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def assign_driver(self, driver):
         self.driver = hashlib.md5(driver.name).hexdigest()

class Driver(models.Model):

    @property
    def car(self):
        try:
            return Car.objects.get(driver=hashlib.md5(self.name).hexdigest())
        except Car.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

This way, you can do `my_driver.car` to fetch the car for this driver of `some_car.assign_driver(my_driver); some_car.save()` to assign and save a driver.

Comment: Naturally `driver.name` must be unique if it's used as the hashed plaintext here, otherwise that `.get()` there may fail with `MultipleObjectsReturned`.

Comment: @AKX is right, you should either make `name` unique on `Driver` or use the `pk` to hash, since you know `pk` is unique.

Comment: Ok this looks nice! Thanks a lot :) I still have one more question though: what I'd ultimately would like to be able to do would be that a Driver could register himself in the Database using DRF API-browser for instance (or via a frontend that make calls to the API),  and declare his car at that moment. Do you know how your solution would play regarding the interaction with the API? Perhaps it's more clear like this: how do you make calls to that function using the API? Thanks again for the help :)

Comment: You still need to write a view for your API and you'd have to use the `assign_driver` function in your view.